# How does "Addressing missing data" help KNN function better?

Tags: knn

Source:- https://machinelearningmastery.com/k-nearest-neighbors-for-machine-learning/

This page has a section quoting the following passage:-

> Best Prepare Data for KNN
>
> **Rescale Data**: KNN performs much better if all of the data has the same scale. Normalizing your data to the range [0, 1] is a good idea. It may also be a good idea to standardize your data if it has a Gaussian
>   distribution.
>
> **Address Missing Data**: Missing data will mean that the distance between samples cannot be calculated. These samples could be excluded or the missing values could be imputed.
>
> **Lower Dimensionality**: KNN is suited for lower dimensional data. You can try it on high dimensional data (hundreds or thousands of input variables) but be aware that it may not perform as well as other techniques. KNN can benefit from feature selection that reduces the dimensionality of the input feature space.

Please, can someone explain the Second point, i.e. Address Missing Data, in detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing data in this context means that some samples do not have all the existing features.

For example:

Suppose you have a database with age and height for a group of individuals.
This would mean that for some persons either the height or the age is missing.

Now, why this affects KNN?

Given a test sample
KNN finds the samples that are closer to it (Aka: the students with similar age and height).
KNN does this to make some inference about the test sample based on its nearest neighbors.

If you want to find these neighbors you must be able to compute the distance between samples. To compute the distance between 2 samples you must have all the features for these 2 samples.

If some of them are missing you won't be able to compute distance. 
So implicitly you would be lossing the samples with missing data

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer! Also, what does "missing values could be imputed" mean?